# Magento media wysiwyg image browser broken in 1.8.1 (only storage root)

Tags: cms, ce-1.8.1.0, wysiwyg

when we are editing a CMS page and want to add an image in Magento 1.8.1 we only see *storage root* in the image browser ... All wysiwyg and subfolders are chmod 777

update: The strange thing is that it does show the files in the root of media/wysiwyg but not the directories or the files in the subdirectories

Did anyone encounter this also. Any suggestions to fix?

thx

Comment: Is your media folder a symlink?

Comment: Nope. The strange thing is that it does show the files in the root of media/wysiwyg but not the directories or the files in the subdirectories

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an issue with Fooman Speedster advanced

We solved by turning MERGE JS OFF .... and clearing cache

(haven't turned it back on again yet)

Answer (score -1):

go to `app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Model/Wysiwyg/` edit the `Config.php` and change const IMAGE_DIRECTORY = 'wysiwyg'; to const IMAGE_DIRECTORY = '.';

Comment: I would not suggest editing the core files like this, if you must make a change like this copy it to local but it would be better to perform a rewrite via config.xml or find a good event to hook onto.